# python file dialog accessing file name

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to use tkinter to open a file dialog, once this file dialogue is open how do i get the file object that is returned by the function. As in how do i access it in main?

basically how do i handle return values by functions that are invoked by command

```
import sys
import Tkinter
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
#import tkMessageBox

def quit_handler():
    print "program is quitting!"
    sys.exit(0)

def open_file_handler():
    file= askopenfilename()
    print file
    return file


main_window = Tkinter.Tk()


open_file = Tkinter.Button(main_window, command=open_file_handler, padx=100, text="OPEN FILE")
open_file.pack()


quit_button = Tkinter.Button(main_window, command=quit_handler, padx=100, text="QUIT")
quit_button.pack()


main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you dont ... or you set a global variable ... typically you would do all your handling in the open_file_handler method, or methods called from that where you pass it as an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning the `file` variable, just handle it there (I also renamed the `file` variable so you do not override the built-in class):

```
def open_file_handler():
    filePath= askopenfilename() # don't override the built-in file class
    print filePath
    # do whatever with the file here
```

Alternatively, you can simply link the button to another function, and handle it there:

```
def open_file_handler():
    filePath = askopenfilename()
    print filePath
    return filePath

def handle_file():
    filePath = open_file_handler()
    # handle the file
```

Then, in the button:

```
open_file = Tkinter.Button(main_window, command=handle_file, padx=100, text="OPEN FILE")
open_file.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way I can think of is to make a `StringVar`

```
file_var = Tkinter.StringVar(main_window, name='file_var')
```

change your callback command using `lambda` to pass the `StringVar` to your callback

```
command = lambda: open_file_handler(file_var)
```

then in your callback, set the `StringVar` to `file`

```
def open_file_handler(file_var):
    file_name = askopenfilename()
    print file_name
    #return file_name
    file_var.set(file_name)
```

Then in your button use `command` instead of `open_file_handler`

```
open_file = Tkinter.Button(main_window, command=command,
                           padx=100, text="OPEN FILE")
open_file.pack()
```

Then you can retrieve the file using

```
file_name = file_var.get()
```